# OpenCV 3.2 file compilation?

Tags: c++, opencv, compilation

How to compile c++ file (opencv included) using opencv 3.2, mingw and command window in Windows 10. (I do not want to use any softwares like codeblocks/Vbasic/eclipse/netbeans).

Comment: Have CMake generate makefiles.

Answer (score 1):

Try using cmake for generating the makefile and then use the same for make and build.

Following is a minimalisitic example of cmake wherein I was using opencv for clustering of pixels.

You need to create a CMakeLists.txt file and add the following things. for more information on building you can check my github repo:
https://github.com/anubhavrohatgi/ImageProcessing.git

```
#Cmake for Clustering Project
PROJECT(clustering)

#Minimum version of Cmake required
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

IF(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
    SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
ENDIF(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)


#Find and add opencv libraries
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED core imgproc highgui imgcodecs)

IF(${OpenCV_VERSION} VERSION_LESS 2.4.12)
    MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "OpenCV version is not compatible : ${OpenCV_VERSION}")
ENDIF()

#Check for C++ Compiler version. I am using C++14.
INCLUDE(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++14" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX14)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++0x" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X)
IF(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX14)
    SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14")
ELSEIF(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X)
    SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++0x")
ELSE()
    MESSAGE(STATUS "The compiler ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} has no C++14 support. Please use a different C++ compiler.")
ENDIF()


#include the header files located in the include folder
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(include)

#Set the variables for Headers and Sources. Manually add the filenames. This 
#is useful if the files are changed, removed or name modified.
#Better than GLOB version
SET(    HEADERS 
    include/clustering.h
)

set(    SOURCES
    src/main.cpp
)

add_executable(clustering ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})

target_link_libraries(clustering
    ${OpenCV_LIBS}
)
```